# PHP - How not to start a session on the login page

Tags: php, session

I use the same header on all pages of my site like this:

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/header.php';
```

The problem is that I also use it for the login page of my website and a session is started as soon as a user accesses it

**login.php**

```
<?php
$test = 'login';
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/header.php';
...
```

**header.php**

```
<?php
session_start (); 
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr" class="no-js">
<head>
...
```

I would like to avoid this, I tried to modify my header.php file like this:

**header.php**

```
<?php
var_dump($test);
if ($test !== 'login') {
  session_start (); 
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr" class="no-js">
<head>
```

But it does not work, while the `var_dump` returns me `login` on the login page (it works well when I remove `session_start ();` from the `header.php` file)

Would you have a solution?

Comment: What's wrong with starting session on login page? that is where you should start your sessions

Comment: I want to start it in the login form and not on the login page

Comment: Not sure if you're familiar with the foundations of PHP sessions, but your "undesired" behavior is not undesired at all. `session_start` will not create a new session on every page load (and if the user's first pageview is the login page, it won't do anything). All that happens is that a cookie check will be performed and any previous session data will persist (or a new session cookie will be set). It's actually a good practice do exactly as you're doing unless there's a compelling technical reason not to.

Comment: If you need more control over when to start a session, don't conflate your HTML header with your session starting business logic. Put those in different files and only include each one as necessary.

Comment: Thank you but all this does not answer my question, I just do not want to create a session on the login page without having to remove the header from all pages of my site.

Comment: It seems that you may be a bit confused with your logic, see my example below. There is no real reason to exclude session functionality from your login page is there? Session is started if it doesn't exist and you can or can not make use of the information within it on the various pages of your website, it is up to you.

Comment: How do you know that `session_start` is getting called?

Comment: @CraigvanTonder Thank you, I have always been taught that the best way to protect something is to hide it. There is no registration form on our website,
unwanted visitors do not need to know the formatting or the size of the ``session_id``

Comment: I guess it really depends on your use case but either way i would still consider revising your architecture in general. If you're very worried that this may be an issue then you could just create or resume the session selectively, so you'd be executing `session_start()` on a specific condition, i.e. when the URL is not publicly accessible or matches a specific set of pages (the ones where you actually use the session functionality).

Answer (score 1):

As one of the comments had said, it seems that you are missing the fundamentals here because you are initializing the session but not actually making use of it.

Assigning a value to a variable is not the same as registering it with the session functionality, see the [basic usage example](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php).

Based on this you might have something like:

**header.php**

```
<?php
if ($_SESSION['test'] !== 'login') {
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['test'] = 'login';
}
...
```

**login.php**

```
<?php
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/header.php';
var_dump($_SESSION['test']);
?>
...
```

I would consider revising your architecture though because you don't need to check if the session is already initialized when [calling session_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php).

Also and in general, doing this from your header doesn't make much sense which will likely end up causing you problems in the future.

I think each of your pages should be formatted more like:

**init.php**

```
<?php
/*  CONFIG FOR APPLICATION
-------------------------- */

// Could potentially define some runtime configuration
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'proddomain.tld') {
  define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');
}
else if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'localhost') {
  define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
}
else {
  echo 'Unknown runtime environment!';
  exit;
}

// Create or resume the session
session_start();

// Testing out session functionality
$_SESSION['test'] = 'hello world';

// Could include some session handling for expiration, etc

// Could include a routing solution

// But fine depending on the page you want to show the header
// So you can make some condition that matches this,
// like check the url to see if it is login.php and if not then include the header
if ($myMagicCondition) {
  require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/navigation.php';
}
```

**anypage.php**

```
<?php
// Include the application configuration
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/init.php';
// Testing runtime constants
var_dump(ENVIRONMENT);
// Testing registered session variable
var_dump($_SESSION['test']);
// The rest of your page
...
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I have this error on login page :  ``Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION``

Comment: @Rocstar Didn't test what I made and threw in something for you to think about but it should work. Show your new code.